# how to calculate the accuracy on the whole train dataset and val dataset respectively

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

Hello I'm a newbie about TensorBoard and tf.metrics.accuracy()

(I am a Chinese so maybe my English is not very well, I will try to describe my question)

**for convenience, I just write the key codes** 
Now I have a problem about save train and val accuracy to TensorBoard every epoch, and my data amount is big, so I use **batch** of data.

What I have finished is:

**1) Get Dataset**

Now, I use

```
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iterator = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, train_iterator.output_types,
                                                       train_iterator.output_shapes)
image_batch, label_batch = iterator.get_next()
```

to get the dataset and I can switch between two datasets within tf.Session() using

```
sess.run([train_iterator.initializer, accuracy_vars_initializer])
```

and

```
sess.run([val_iterator.initializer, accuracy_vars_initializer])
```

**2) calculate accuracy**

```
with tf.name_scope("meters"):
    accuracy, accuracy_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=label_batch,
                                                predictions=tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits_batch), -1),
                                                name="accuracy")
    accuracy_value_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
    accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy_value_)

accuracy_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope="meters/accuracy")  
accuracy_vars_initializer = tf.variables_initializer(var_list=accuracy_vars)
```

I use

```
sess.run(accuracy_vars_initializer)
```

before the train/val process on the whole train/val dataset to set the internal counting value within tf.metrics.accuracy()
then I want use

```
for epoch_i in range(FLAGS.epoch):
    sess.run([train_iterator.initializer, accuracy_vars_initializer])
        train_loss_avg, train_acc_avg = [], []
        while True:
            try:
                _, loss_value, step, acc_value, acc_op_value, summary = sess.run(
                    [train_op, loss, global_step, accuracy, accuracy_op, merged],
                    feed_dict={handle: train_iterator_handle,
                               accuracy_value_: np.average(train_acc_avg),
                               loss_value_: np.average(train_loss_avg)})
                train_acc_avg.append(acc_value)
                train_loss_avg.append(loss_value)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                train_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
                saver.save(sess, os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, "fcn8.ckpt"), global_step)
                print("train dataset finished")
                break

        sess.run([val_iterator.initializer, accuracy_vars_initializer])
        val_loss_avg = []
        while True:
            try:
                loss_value, acc_value, acc_op_value, summary = sess.run(
                    [loss, accuracy, accuracy_op, merged], feed_dict={handle: val_iterator_handle,
                                                                      accuracy_value_: acc_op_value,
                                                                      loss_value_: np.average(val_loss_avg)})

                print("Epoch[%d],val batch loss = %g,acc = %g." % (epoch_i, loss_value, acc_value))
                val_loss_avg.append(loss_value)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                val_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
                print("val dataset finished")
                break
    train_writer.close()
    val_writer.close()
```

to achieve my goal.

The accuracy calculating method I used before is simply

```
feed_dict={handle: train_iterator_handle,
accuracy_value_: accuracy_op,
loss_value_: np.average(train_loss_avg)})
```

**But both the old and new method will result in a horizontal accuracy line in TensorBoard. And I improved my code many times but the problem still exists**
[image]

Can anyone help me to find the reason? And is there a better and standardized way to structure my code? Because it's too complicated right now.

**Many thanks for any help.**